# Vector Proof for triple product

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

How can I prove/disprove $\vec A\times(\vec B\times\vec C)=(\vec A\times \vec B)\times\vec C +\vec B\times(\vec A\times\vec C)$ ?

I know I could equate the right side to:
$\vec B(\vec A \cdot\vec C)-\vec C(\vec A \cdot\vec B)$
But I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: WOlfram says it's not always equal, so I'm trying to find examples.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Levi-Civita symbol (also known as epsilon tensor)?

Comment: no, tell me more or I can google it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol It is sometimes helpful in proving identities like the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector triple product satisfies the Jacobi identity:
$$ a \times (b \times c) + b \times ( c \times a) + c \times (a \times b) =0, $$
because Lagrange's identity implies that the left-hand side expands to
$$ b(c \cdot a)-c(a \cdot b) + c(a \cdot b)-a(b \cdot c)+a(b \cdot c)-b(c \cdot a), $$
and everything cancels. This is equivalent to your expression by the anticommutativity of the cross product, so it is always true.

Comment: So in a situation like this, whose answer should I choose? Theyr'll all correct I think...

Answer (score 1):

This is the Jacobi identity for the vector cross product. Since you already have the identity:

$$
\mathbf{a}\times(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})=\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})-\mathbf{c}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})
$$

applying this to both sides should show you they are equivalent. The left-hand side is:

$$
LHS=\mathbf{a}\times(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})=\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})-\mathbf{c}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})
$$

and the right-hand side is:

$$
\begin{split} RHS&=(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})\times\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{b}\times(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{c}) \\ &=-\mathbf{c}\times(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})+\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c})-\mathbf{c}(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{a}) \\ &=-\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{b})+\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{a})+\mathbf{a}(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c})-\mathbf{c}(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{a}) \\ &=\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})-\mathbf{c}(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{a})=LHS \end{split}
$$